# Max and min value of $f(x,y,z) = xyz + xy$ on $K = \{x\geq0 , y\geq0, z\geq0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1 \}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the maximum and minimum value of $f(x,y,z) = xyz + xy$ on
$$K = \{x\geq0 , y\geq0, z\geq0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1 \}.$$
I know the procedure when there are two variables, but I get confused when there are three variables.
When I find the gradient, I get a non-linear system of equations:

\begin{align*}
yz+y &= 0 \\
xz+x &= 0 \\
xy &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

I don't understand how I'm supposed to solve this.
I'm also confused about what to do on the border $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Am I supposed to bring in trigonometric functions or is there an alternative. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spherical coordinates are natural for describing $K$ since it's a chunk of the unit sphere. Note that $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$ and similarly with $x(z+1)=0$ and $y(z+1)=0$. This will put some strong restrictions on which angles and radii satisfy the system. So the trig is a good way forward. Give it a go then circle back if you need more help.

Comment: Did you try using Lagrange multipliers? @Hejhelohola

Comment: No, we have not done Lagrange multipliers yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's evident that the minimum of $K$ is $0$ and this minimum is reached if and only if $x =0$ or $y = 0$.

For the maximum, we have:
$$\begin{align}
K = xy(1+z) &\le \frac{x^2 +y^2}{2} \cdot (1+z) \hspace{1cm} \text{(AM-GM inequality)}\\
&\le \frac{1}{2}(1-z^2)(1+z) \hspace{1cm} \text{(from }x^2 +y^2 +z^2 \le 1)\\ 
&=2 \cdot \frac{1+z}{2}\cdot  \frac{1+z}{2}\cdot (1-z)
\\ 
&\le 2\cdot\left(\frac{\frac{1+z}{2}+  \frac{1+z}{2}+ (1-z)}{3}  \right)^3 = \frac{16}{27} \hspace{1cm} \text{(AM-GM inequality)}\\
\end{align}$$
Then, the maximum is $16/27$ and is reached if and only if $$\cases{x=y\\x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\\\frac{1+z}{2} = 1-z}\iff (x,y,z) =(2/3,2/3,1/3)$$